# Postgresql: How to select from the sql results twice

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am using PostgreSQL to write an SQL query to select from the same sql results twice. For example,

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
  FROM
    (SELECT * FROM tableA) as a,
    (SELECT * FROM tableA) as b
  WHERE a.id = b.id+1
```

As you can see the following SQL query has been executed twice:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
```

Is it possible to store the SQL results temporarily instead of running the same query twice because this query can be complicated?

Comment: What about a join of `tableA` with itself ?  Something like: `SELECT a.id,b.id from tableA a join tableB b on a.id=b.id+1`

Comment: The line "SELECT * FROM tableA" is just an example and it could be complicated nested queries.

Comment: If the `SELECT * from tableA` can't be replaced by a view, you can use also a sub-query using [with](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common Table Expression:

```
with cte as 
(SELECT * FROM tableA)
select * from cte where...
```

So you don't have to write the same stuff twice. Don't know if its executed once or severel times though...

Comment: What I'm wondering (and I'm honestly not sure, and that seems to be OP's question): if you refer to the CTE twice in your query, are you guaranteed that the CTE will only be executed once?

Comment: I don't know, check the execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

A CTE solves your problem.  But it is likely that the `lead()` function would as well . . . and with better performance:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.id, lead(a.id) over (order by a.id) as b_id
      FROM tableA a
     ) a
WHERE id = b_id;
```

Or, for something that will work with duplicates:

```
SELECT a.id, a.id + 1
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA a2 WHERE a2.id = a.id + 1);
```

A self-join seems like overkill for whatever you really want to accomplish.  It might be the right solution, but there are alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cte`.

```
with a as (select * from tableA)
, b as (select * from tableA)
select a.id, b.id 
from a join b on a.id = b.id+1
```

Or it could be done with a `self-join`.

```
select a.id, b.id 
from tableA a join tableB b
on a.id = b.id+1
```